# What's the equivalent of Rails' Migrations or Django's South in Pylons and TG2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django, pylons, turbogears

Does anyone know how Pylons and TG2 projects handle database migrations?  I'm looking for something similar to Rails' Migrations and Django's South.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Santi said, it doesn't have its own, but some of the ones available for SQLAlchemy should work:

[sqlalchemy-migrate](http://code.google.com/p/sqlalchemy-migrate/) which is also used by [tesla-pylons-elixir](http://code.google.com/p/tesla-pylons-elixir/wiki/Migrations) as a way to get better integration with Pylons.

[miruku](http://trac.ollix.org/miruku/)

Comment: just to clarify sqlachemy-migrate is the tool to use. Although SA0.6 may make it obsolete. Remember do not repeat yourself.

Comment: It's worth noting that sqlalchemy-migrate doesn't yet work with PostgreSQL IF you use a schema other than public.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know. Pylons doesn't have it's own integrated ORM, you have to integrate that yourself or just code your own DB layer. So, al least for Pylons, you either have to build your own script, getting all the content from one DB and putting it inside the new one; or you have to look in the ORM of your choise for tools available.